# get Drop Target of component

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi, I want to get Drop target className/ID after Drop Event. Does anybody tell me how to get ?**

```
<div class="drop_1" id="drop1"></div>

<div class="drop_2" id="drop2"></div>

<div class="drop_3" id="drop3"></div>
```

***all DIV component must be drag-able & drop-able onto each other***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bibhaw/xqZC9/4/)

```
$(function() {

      ***/* Make draggable */***

        $(".drop_1, .drop_2, .drop_3").draggable();

        var dropOpts = {
        accept:".drop_1, .drop_2, .drop_3",
        drop:dropCallback,
        greedy:true
          };

    /* Droppable */

    $(".drop_1, .drop_2, .drop_3").droppable(dropOpts);

    /*get your Drop target*/

     function dropCallback(e) {
        alert("The firing droppable was " + e.target.className);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use the this.id inside the drop handler

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/red_square/Mevmb/4/)

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {
       console.log(this.id);
   }
});
```

Comment: @redsquare i mean your given [link's example](http://jsfiddle.net/red_square/Mevmb/3/)

Comment: @redsquare the question is **to get the Drop target** class/Id name, right? [take a look of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bibhaw/xqZC9/4/)

Comment: ah the droppable! ok ya get it now!